# Ingest email attachments on ElasticSearch

Tags: email, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to use ELK pipeline to read an email (IMAP), extract generic attachments (mainly PDF, eventually doc or ppt) and put them on ElasticSearch.

This is what I was able to do:

1. Loading directly to ElasticSearch from file some base64 data using Logstash, using the `Ingest Attachment Processor` on ElasticSearch to read the base64 content.
2. Loading data from IMAP (exchange email) I can correctly load all email information on ElasticSearch except the attachment (what I need).

The first solution works fine and does what I am looking for, except that it doesn't extract attachments directly from the email and that I have hardcoded base64 data inside the files.
With the second solution I have a field `x-ms-has-attach: yes` on Kibana, but there isn't anywhere the attachment itself. The `imap` plugin is intended to load only the content of the email without the attachment?

What am I missing? Could you suggest me a pipeline to achieve what I am looking for?

This is my logstash configuration for the **first example**:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/my/path/to/data/*"
    start_position => "beginning"
#    sincedb_path => "/my/path/to/sincedb"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    close_older => 0
    tags => ["attachment"]
   }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index     => "email-attachment"
    hosts     => [ "localhost:9200" ]
  }
}
```

This is the pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/email-attachment
{
  "description": "Pipeline to parse an email and its attachments",
  "processors": [
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "message"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove" : {
        "field" : "message"
      }
    },
    {
      "date_index_name" : {
        "field" : "@timestamp",
        "index_name_prefix" : "email-attachment-",
        "index_name_format": "yyyy-MM",
        "date_rounding" : "M"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my logstash configuration for the **second example**:

```
input {
  imap {
    host => "my.domain.it"
    password => "mypassword"
    user => "myuser"
    port => 12345
    type => "imap"
    secure => true
    strip_attachment => true
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index     => "email-attachment"
    hosts     => [ "localhost:9200" ]
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I'm using version `5.2.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I defined a totally different pipeline.
I read emails using a Ruby application with the `mail` library (you can find it on `github`), where it's quite easy to extract attachments.
Then I put the `base64` encoding of those attachments directly on `ElasticSearch`, using `Ingest Attachment Processor`.

I filter on `content_type` just to be sure to load only "real" attachments, as the multiparts emails treat any multimedial content in the body (ie: images) as attachment.

**P.S.**

Using the [mail library](http://github.com/mikel/mail), you should do something like:

```
Mail.defaults do
    retriever_method :imap, { :address =>                 address,
                              :port =>                    port,
                              :user_name =>               user_name,
                              :password =>                password,
                              :enable_ssl =>              enable_ssl,
                              :openssl_verify_mode =>     openssl_verify_mode }
```

and `new_messages = Mail.find(keys: ['NOT','SEEN'])` to retrieve unseen messages.

Then iterate over new_messages. After, you can encode a message simply using `encoded = Base64.strict_encode64(attachment.body.to_s)`. Please inspect `new_messages` to check the exact field names to use.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which script you're using for a) pulling the emails and b) bas64 encoding the attachments ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might come from `strip_attachment => true` in the imap input plugin.

Comment: There are no information in the documentation on this option, but you can see in the code of the plugin what it does: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-imap/blob/33aca04048dd1bc53738a0b219b1db5bf962ec9d/lib/logstash/inputs/imap.rb#L85

Comment: I forgot to mention but I already tried, setting it to `strip_attachment => true` doesn't solve the problem. I also tried to force the default value `false`, just in case, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli I don't have any other idea. Perhaps the server does not send the attachements by default.

Comment: Yes, I suspect it too. Exchange could be the problem. Maybe I will try with another domain, just to confirm or exclude this eventuality. Thanks for your help!